# How could I return a different ServerResponse if Flux stream data has error status

Tags: spring-webflux

I am implementing a REST endpoint using WebFlux and I do not have any problem working on basic operations but there is an operation I do not know how to manage.
I would like to return PriceMessage objects related to an Event object so if the event exists the endpoint returns a ServerResponse.ok() but a ServerResponse.notFound() should be returned if the Event does not exist.

In the repository layer there is the following method that returns an Mono representing a code if and Event with eventId exists and a Mono.empty() if it does not:

```
@Override
public Mono<Integer> getSportsEventId(long eventId) {
  Optional<SourceEventDto> optionalSourceEvent =
    springJpaSourceEventRepository.findByEventId(eventId);

  Mono<Integer> result = Mono.empty();

  if (optionalSourceEvent.isPresent()) {
    result = Mono.just(new Integer(optionalSourceEvent.get().getSourceId()));
  }

  return result;
}
```

Then, the service layer returns a Flux which sets an error if the event was not found or connects to Redis to get the prices related to the sportsEventId:

```
@Override
public Flux<PriceMessage> getPrices(long eventId) {
  return
    // get the sportsEventId
    sourceEventRepository.getSportsEventId(eventId)
      // notify the event does not exist
      .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new IllegalStateException("Event " + eventId + " does not exist")))
      // get the related PriceEntity objects
      .flatMapMany(priceRepository::findBySporsEventId)
      // transform to PriceMessage
      .map(priceMessageFactory::from);
}
```

This code is unit tested and I also debugged it to be sure flatMapMany and map parts are not called if an error is set in the stream.

Finally, in the REST layer there is this code, the happy path:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getPricesByEventId(ServerRequest request) {
  String eventIdParam = request.pathVariable("eventId");

  // call the service layer
  Flux<PriceMessage> prices = priceService.getPrices(eventId);

  return
    ServerResponse.ok()
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
      .body(prices, PriceMessage.class);
}
```

This works fine but I do not know how to return an 404 error if prices stream contains an error because the event was not found, setting in the body the error message, something like this:

```
ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
  .syncBody(<error_message_from_flux>);
```

Pseudocode would be something like this but I cannot translate it into reactive:

```
if (!prices.isError()) then
  return
    ServerResponse.ok()
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
      .body(prices, PriceMessage.class);
else
  return
    ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
     .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
     .syncBody(<error_message_from_flux>);
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use onErrorResume to create an Error Response in case an error occurs.

```
 return priceService.getPrices(eventId).flatMap(prices -> ServerResponse.ok()
          .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
          .body(prices, PriceMessage.class))
       .onErrorResume(err -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body({Your Error Body Here}).build());
```

Comment: Both flatMap and onErrorResume operations return a Flux<ServerResponse> instead of a Mono<ServerResponse>. Anyways, flatMap code would be called as many times as prices are returned which is not the expected behaviour.

Comment: The flatMap will not be called after an error has occured

Answer (score 0):

You can use choose to handle it while registering routes.

```java
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(PriceMessageHandler handler) {
  return RouterFunctions.route().GET("/",
      request -> ServerResponse.ok().body(handler.handle(request), PriceMessage.class))
      .onError(Exception.class, (e, a) -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).build())
      .build();
}
```

Or you can user `onErrorResume` on ServerResponse:

```java
return ServerResponse.ok().body(priceService.getPrices(eventId), PriceMessage.class).onErrorResume((e) -> ServerResponse.notFound().build());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution presents the same problem as the previous one. WebFlux expects a Mono<ServerResponse> to be returned while its body could be a Flux<PriceMessages> (which can be empty) or a String containing the error message.

Comment: If you want a mono you can convert flux response to mono by `priceService.getPrices(eventId).collectList()`. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Would not collectList block until all the price sequence is completed in order to create the List of PriceMessage? It is expected the number of prices to be higher than 50,000 and the whole idea is to send them one by one as soon as they are available. In this solution latency will be impacted, will not it?